# Error while converting .py file to .exe using pyinstaller in windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, exe, pyinstaller

I have converted an exe file to pyc files using  pyinstxtractor.py, then decompiled those files using uncompyle6. Updated the code and compiled those files.
Then decompiled the entry point file by adding python header from other file.
when running
pyinstaller gui.py
I am getting errors.

I tried with python 2.7 as application is built using this version only.

```
E:\PYZ-00.pyz_extracted>pyinstaller gu
i.py
184 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.4
184 INFO: Python: 2.7.16
184 INFO: Platform: Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1
189 INFO: wrote E:\mytest\orig exe\xxxxxx.exe_extracted\PYZ-00.pyz_extracte
d\gui.spec
190 INFO: UPX is not available.
194 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['E:\\mytest\\orig exe\\xxxxxx.exe_extracted\\PYZ-00.pyz_extracted',
 'E:\\mytest\\orig exe\\xxxxxx.exe_extracted\\PYZ-00.pyz_extracted']
196 INFO: checking Analysis
196 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
196 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
203 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
245 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
275 INFO: Adding Microsoft.VC90.CRT to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\python27\python.exe
1217 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt
_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21009.1_none_18ff9d83d18b6187.manifest
1236 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt
_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_18f8a87fd1919cd9.manifest
1252 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt
_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.1_none_3da38fdebd0e6822.manifest
1259 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt
_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4148_none_acd0e4ffe1daef0a.manifest
1273 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt
_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4940_none_acd19a1fe1da248a.manifest
1286 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt
_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_acd388d7e1d8689f.manifest
1371 INFO: Searching for assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.
30729.6161_none ...
1371 INFO: Found manifest C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1
fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_08e61857a83bc251.manifest
1374 INFO: Searching for file msvcr90.dll
1374 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3
b_9.0.30729.6161_none_08e61857a83bc251\msvcr90.dll
1375 INFO: Searching for file msvcp90.dll
1375 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3
b_9.0.30729.6161_none_08e61857a83bc251\msvcp90.dll
1375 INFO: Searching for file msvcm90.dll
1375 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3
b_9.0.30729.6161_none_08e61857a83bc251\msvcm90.dll
1444 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt
_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21009.1_none_18ff9d83d18b6187.manifest
1446 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt
_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_18f8a87fd1919cd9.manifest
1447 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt
_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.1_none_3da38fdebd0e6822.manifest
1447 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt
_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4148_none_acd0e4ffe1daef0a.manifest
1449 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt
_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4940_none_acd19a1fe1da248a.manifest
1450 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt
_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_acd388d7e1d8689f.manifest
1450 INFO: Adding redirect Microsoft.VC90.CRT version (9, 0, 21022, 8) -> (9, 0,
 30729, 6161)
1496 INFO: Caching module hooks...
1502 INFO: Analyzing E:\mytest\orig exe\xxxxxx.exe_extracted\PYZ-00.pyz_ext
racted\gui.py
2860 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   _xmlplus
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('PyInstaller==3.4', 'console_scripts', 'pyinstaller')()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 111, in run

    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 63, in run_
build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line
838, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'
))
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line
784, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line
241, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line
158, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line
443, in assemble
    priority_scripts.append(self.graph.run_script(script))
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 201,
 in run_script
    self._top_script_node = super(PyiModuleGraph, self).run_script(pathname)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py
", line 1348, in run_script
    self._scan_code(m, co, co_ast)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py
", line 2544, in _scan_code
    self._process_imports(module)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py
", line 2743, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py
", line 2221, in _safe_import_hook
    target_attr_names=None, level=level, edge_attr=edge_attr)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py
", line 1421, in import_hook
    source_package, target_module_partname, level)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py
", line 1573, in _find_head_package
    target_module_headname, target_package_name, source_package)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 271,
 in _safe_import_module
    module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py
", line 1990, in _safe_import_module
    module_name, file_handle, pathname, metadata)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py
", line 2082, in _load_module
    self._scan_code(m, co, co_ast)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py
", line 2544, in _scan_code
    self._process_imports(module)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py
", line 2743, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py
", line 2221, in _safe_import_hook
    target_attr_names=None, level=level, edge_attr=edge_attr)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py
", line 1421, in import_hook
    source_package, target_module_partname, level)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py
", line 1573, in _find_head_package
    target_module_headname, target_package_name, source_package)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 271,
 in _safe_import_module
    module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py
", line 1990, in _safe_import_module
    module_name, file_handle, pathname, metadata)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py
", line 2082, in _load_module
    self._scan_code(m, co, co_ast)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py
", line 2544, in _scan_code
    self._process_imports(module)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py
", line 2743, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py
", line 2221, in _safe_import_hook
    target_attr_names=None, level=level, edge_attr=edge_attr)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py
", line 1421, in import_hook
    source_package, target_module_partname, level)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py
", line 1573, in _find_head_package
    target_module_headname, target_package_name, source_package)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 271,
 in _safe_import_module
    module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py
", line 1990, in _safe_import_module
    module_name, file_handle, pathname, metadata)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py
", line 2082, in _load_module
    self._scan_code(m, co, co_ast)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py
", line 2544, in _scan_code
    self._process_imports(module)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py
", line 2743, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py
", line 2221, in _safe_import_hook
    target_attr_names=None, level=level, edge_attr=edge_attr)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py
", line 1421, in import_hook
    source_package, target_module_partname, level)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py
", line 1573, in _find_head_package
    target_module_headname, target_package_name, source_package)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 271,
 in _safe_import_module
    module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py
", line 1990, in _safe_import_module
    module_name, file_handle, pathname, metadata)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py
", line 2082, in _load_module
    self._scan_code(m, co, co_ast)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py
", line 2544, in _scan_code
    self._process_imports(module)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py
", line 2743, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py
", line 2221, in _safe_import_hook
    target_attr_names=None, level=level, edge_attr=edge_attr)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py
", line 1421, in import_hook
    source_package, target_module_partname, level)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py
", line 1573, in _find_head_package
    target_module_headname, target_package_name, source_package)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 271,
 in _safe_import_module
    module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py
", line 1990, in _safe_import_module
    module_name, file_handle, pathname, metadata)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py
", line 2082, in _load_module
    self._scan_code(m, co, co_ast)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py
", line 2544, in _scan_code
    self._process_imports(module)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py
", line 2743, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py
", line 2221, in _safe_import_hook
    target_attr_names=None, level=level, edge_attr=edge_attr)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py
", line 1421, in import_hook
    source_package, target_module_partname, level)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py
", line 1573, in _find_head_package
    target_module_headname, target_package_name, source_package)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 260,
 in _safe_import_module
    hook_module.pre_safe_import_module(hook_api)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\pre_safe_import_module\h
ook-_xmlplus.py", line 31, in pre_safe_import_module
    for p in api.module_graph.findNode('xml').packagepath:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

exe should be generated. 
my work is similar as
https://hshrzd.wordpress.com/2018/01/26/solving-a-pyinstaller-compiled-crackme/

Comment: Are you trying to reverse engineer an executable created with pyinstaller?

Comment: Right, I already completed first part. Which was to get to code and now next part is to make executable again, in that step I am getting errors. Any pointers to resolve this?

Comment: Can you run the `gui.py` directly from python without error ?

Comment: When I run python gui.py standalone then it doesn't compile because of dependencies. So I copied it to PYZ-00.pyz_extracted folder then there also standalone compilation fails. So I complied the whole directory at once then it was done.

Comment: You need to first try to run `gui.py` without any problem and then try to freeze it again with pyinstaller you need to know what is the dependencies of `gui.py` and provide them first.

Comment: when run directly outside of folder 
```
F:\Python Test\Test6_12062019\orig exe\xxxxx.exe_extracted>python guii.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "guii.py", line 7, in <module>
    from cftelegram import CFTelegram
ImportError: No module named cftelegram

Comment: When Run inside PYZ-00.pyz_extracted folder,
F:\Python Test\Test6_12062019\orig exe\xxxxx.exe_extracted\PYZ-00.pyz_extracted>python guii.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "guii.py", line 5, in <module>
    import Tkinter, ttk, time
  File "F:\Python Test\Test6_12062019\orig exe\xxxxx.exe_extracted\PYZ-00.pyz_extracted\Tkinter.py", line 9, in <module>
    from Tkinter import _cnfmerge, _default_root, _flatten, _support_default_root, _test, _tkinter, _setit
ImportError: cannot import name _cnfmerge

Comment: Thanks, i'll try to sort out these first.

Comment: @RSGamer Hi, did you accomplish your goal? I can help you. Give me your telegram or other for faster communication. I know what you want to hack, and I just hacked it.